# Can't get to work php script using file_get_content or cURL

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have this issue please.
I use this script here to send an automatic SMS:

```
<?php
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://url.goes.here:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=user&passwd=password&type=0&dlr=1&destination=phone&source=FLM&message=hello');
?>
```

The issue is, if i submit the URL directly i get something like:

```
1701|355662080090|a2406d38-1baf-42a2-a1a5-e5798859e400
```

And a sms arrives to my phone, but if i use the above methods i won't get the sms..
Anyone can suggest me why is so?
Thanks..

Comment: so `file_get_contents("http://url.goes.here:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=user&passwd=password&type=0&dlr=1&destination=phone&source=FLM&message=hello")` doesn't work? Maybe because `allow_url_fopen` is disabled?

Comment: Can you  please help me with a way to do this? which doesn't rely on disabled or enabled features..

Comment: the issue is, it's an external site and i have no rights to it, i can't enable or disable features

Comment: What's the output of `ini_get('allow_url_open');`?

Comment: @al_alb: also, we're talking about `allow_url_fopen` in **your** site.

Comment: Amal yes,in my site it is enabled!

Comment: What is the output of file_get_contents?

Comment: It won't output anything, but if i cope-paste the url to the   browser i get something like: 1701|355662080090|a2406d38-1baf-42a2-a1a5-e5798859e400

Comment: Your cURL code looks correct.  Does the site validate user agents or something?  It may be blocking the request because of the way the request is formatted.  Try to print the results of curl_error($ch) after your request completes and see the results.

Comment: tried that, i get nothing, no error...
is there any other way i can do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you DO have allow_url_fopen activated in your php.ini, then you should look into changing the user agent for the request (use cURL).
Many SMS gateways use user agent filtering when processing their requests...
Correct me if I am wrong, but I suppose you use RouteSMS, right?